# Linux email sending error: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, ssl, postfix-mta, smtplib, oserror

For some reason I have an error while running this code:

```py
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com.tr', 465) as server:
    server.login(email_from, password_from)
    server.sendmail(
        from_addr='mymail@yandex.ru',
        to_addrs='yourmail@yandex.ru',
        msg='Hello'
    )
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "report.py", line 86, in <module>
    send_report()
  File "report.py", line 82, in send_report
    notificate(*create_html_msg())
  File "report.py", line 69, in notificate
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com.tr', 465, context=context) as server:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1034, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1040, in _get_socket
    new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

OS is Ubuntu 20.04. My code runs perfectly on the other machine, so the problem is obviously somewhere with the machine.

I've tried:

```sh
sudo ufw allow 465/tcp
```

Also I installed and run postfix mail server and added this to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
```

and then restarted postfix with

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

But nothing solved the problem. Please help me with this error.

Comment: What happens if you just do `telnet smtp.yandex.com.tr 465`?

Comment: Your postfix server is irrelevant if you're connecting to a remote SMTP server with smtplib.

Comment: *"My code runs perfectly on the other machine, so the problem is obviously somewhere with __the machine__."* - more likely the problem is in the network. While there is absolutely nothing known about your environment my guess is that you are in a network where a firewall blocks such connections. There is nothing you can do about this except being in another network.

Comment: @Barmar, I've got this: ```Trying 77.88.21.158...
Trying 2a02:6b8::19d...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable```

Comment: That confirms that the problem has nothing to do with the Python script or postfix. It's a network issue, most likely a firewall as @SteffenUllrich said.